# Почему ссылки в navbar сдвигаются вправо?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, bootstrap4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
    MyBrandName
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Делал по туториалу на ютубе, и в том видео 3 ссылки Home были прижаты влево, но у меня они почему-то прижаты вправо. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте класс `justify-content-start` к `<nav>`